# Laravel Cartalyst Sentinel - register rollback

Tags: php, laravel

Can Cartalyst sentinel register be roll backed due to failure in actions like insertion into other tables or mail send error

Comment: What did you investigate?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if that is a Cartalyst feature or not, but you could always use a database transaction:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#database-transactions

```
 try {
    DB::beginTransaction();

    // do registration

    // send email. oh no it failed. throw exception

 catch (EmailFailedException $e) {
      DB::rollBack();
 }
```